# C++ creating a constructor (copy) for a class that has a reference member variable but passing a reference to a base class as a argument

Tags: c++, inheritance, constructor, reference

I have a class `ModelRecorder` with contains a reference modelRef_ to another class `OpModel`.

```
class ModelRecorder : public CompositionalModel //This is an abstract base        class
{

    OpModel& modelRef_;
};
```

When an instance of `ModelRecorder` is created, `modelRef_` is initialized. Thats fine I unerstand that.

How would I write a constructor(copy constructor?) for `ModelRecorder` so that if another instance is created, the reference memeber `modelRef_` will be initalized with the previous created `OpModel` instance?

Note that `CompositionalModel` is an abstract base class.

In another class there is a method that returns a reference to the `CompositionalModel` base class. I understand returning the narrower base class is a good OOP.

This is the method:

```
mv::CompositionalModel& mv::CompilationUnit::recordedModel()
{
    return *recordedModel_;
}
```

I want to pass this reference to the base class to a constructor for `ModelRecorder` so that the reference memeber `modelRef_` will be initalized with the previous created `OpModel` instance?

I tried this but it gives the error below, which is correct as `modelRef` is a member of the dereived class `ModelRecorder` and not the base class `CompositionalModel`.

error: ‘const class mv::CompositionalModel’ has no member named ‘modelRef_

```
mv::ModelRecorder::ModelRecorder(const CompositionalModel& arg) : CompositionalModel{static_cast<const ModelRecorder&>(arg)}, modelRef_{arg.modelRef_}
{
}
```

Comment: If you follow [the rule of zero](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three#Rule_of_zero) it should work out of the box.

Comment: Also note that the "copy-constructor" you show isn't really a copy-constructor, it's a *converting constructor*. A copy-constructor for the `ModelRecorder` class would take a `const ModelRecorder&` argument.

Comment: Again, you should post a [MCVE]. People aren't saying this to annoy you, it is simply impossible to give you a good solution if we are missing 90% of the information. It doesn't have to be your actual code, just something that demonstrates the situation (which you are doing with words right now). Notice how the comments here go in all directions and how the answer to your previous question didn't actually solve your problem because you left out important information.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Ore no cast at all with `ModelRecorder(const ModelRecorder& arg)`

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude The worst part about this is that it steps on the toes of the actual copy constructor if you try to pass a `ModelRecorder`...

Comment: Why not store `OpModel*` ? Then the default copy constructor would do what you want by default. The only difference is the syntax.